Why Lint recommends using standard Guava for an Android project
In my build.gradle I have defined Guava dependency as follows:
implementation("com.google.guava:guava:33.2.1-android")
This is flagged by Lint:
A newer version of com.google.guava:guava than 33.2.1-android is available: 33.2.1-jre
But this is not a newer version, this is a different version (not an android version).
Is there a valid reason for a such behaviour or this is a mistake by Lint?
I tried both versions and they both working fine, but according Guava documentation (https://github.com/google/guava) I should use android version (for my android project).

The way that we use the version number in Guava is certainly not normal (though it was the best we could do, I promise), so I think it's more our fault than the fault of this lint tool. (Which tool is it, incidentally?) There's a chance that you may be able to declare a dependency on the -jre version and rely on Gradle to automatically select the Android version for you, so you could try that (but leave a comment for future readers! :)) to see if it quiets the warning.
